# RepoDb does not seem to work for SQL Server tables with dot in the name

Tags: sql-server, micro-orm

I'm starting to use RepoDb, but my SQL Server 2016 database has tables with a dot in the middle like this: `User.Data`.

Moving from full .NET Entity Framework to RepoDb, I'm facing this issue. I'm using the fluent mapping and I wrote something like this:

```cs
FluentMapper
    .Entity<UserData>()
    .Table("[User.Data]")
    .Primary(u => u.UserId)
```

I get the exception: `MissingFieldsException` and it says:

> There are no database fields found for table '[User.Data]'. Make sure that the target table '[User.Data]' is present in the database and/or at least a single field is available.

Just for curiosity, I created a table `UserData` with the same attributes and primary key and it worked great (change the fluent mapper whit:  `.Table("[UserData]")`.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Are you sure it's a table called `User.Data` and not a table called `Data` in the schema `User`? Either way, using tables with a `.` in the object name is a very confusing, and poor idea, as is using a name which is a reserved keyword (`USER` is a reserved keyword, if the object is on a schema called `User`). You should endeavour to use object names that do not require delimit identifying. Personally, if you're not too far into the development cycle, that you rename that object/schema.

Comment: If you have trouble with schemas, you probably *shouldn't* be changing the ORM. EF Core isn't broken and some of RepoDB's features are typically *not* needed in an ORM, they are really advanced concepts. For example, EF Core's DbSet implements the Repository pattern already and DbContext *is* a Unit-of-Work. RepoDB's bulk insert wraps object in an IDbDataReader and use SqlBulkCopy. That's *not* something needed in an ORM, that's ETL and plain-old ADO.NET.

Comment: There's no real "bulk" update or delete either, RepoDB stores the data in a temporary table and performs a MERGE with the target table. Once again, that's ADO.NET, no objects are really involved. Are you *sure* you need those features?

Comment: Hi Roberto, thanks for asking. Unfortunately, RepoDb does not parse a table with a '.' in its name. Though it is very unlikely that the name choices coincide with the schema separator, but still a valid real-world use-case. In short, we consider it as a bug. Please allow us to revert to you once the new beta release is deployed. But I do agree with Larnu's comment to simply avoid naming the tables that may trigger a conflict against the reserve keywords etc.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the answers. Unfortunately, the schema name is not cited in my example. I know that the this naming convetion was a bad choice but at that time I was not aware of the best practices for the database names. Now I've to deal with it and try to change in the future but now it's not possible. Thanks, Micheal for understanding the situation. I'll wait for the beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support to this in only available at [RepoDb.SqlServer (v1.0.13)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RepoDb.SqlServer/1.0.13) version or above. You can use either of the approaches below. Make sure to specify the quotes if you are using the database and schema.

Via built-in `MapAttribute`.

```
[Map("[User.Data]")]
```

Via `TableAttribute` of the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.

```
[Table("[User.Data]")]
```

Via `FluentMapper` as you did.

```
FluentMapper
    .Entity<UserData>()
    .Table("[User.Data]");
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I used the FluentMapper. Thanks a lot!